# Function is not called after saving to firebase emulator storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-tools

When I upload a file to the emulator's storage, onUploadFile is not called. I have no idea what the cause is.version     "express": "^4.18.2","firebase-admin": "^11.8.0","firebase-functions": "^4.6.0".
There are no errors in the emulator, and the storage is still there.

> export const onUploadFile = functions.storage   .object()
> .onFinalize(async (object) => {
> console.log(object);
> console.log("test");   });

This did not work.

```
import { useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react';

import { ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';
import { storage } from '../firebaseConfig';

export const Upload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      setFile(files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (file) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `/${file.name}`);
      console.log(storageRef, 'storageRef');
      try {
        const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
        console.log(
          snapshot.metadata.fullPath
        );
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import app from "./server/server";
// eslint-disable-next-line object-curly-spacing
import { onObjectFinalized } from "firebase-functions/v2/storage";

export const api = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 500,
  })
  .https.onRequest(app);

export const onUploadFile = onObjectFinalized(async (object) => {
  console.log(object, "test");
});
```

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "frontend/build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "storage": { "port": 9199 }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show what the emulator does output after you perform whatever upload that should trigger the function.